Microphone input in website in webview for swiftui
I have a website of a chatbot that also accepts microphone inputs and I embedded that into my swift and the everything other than the mic is working. I have included permission in the info file and here's some of the code :
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import AVFoundation

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: WebView

        init(parent: WebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                completionHandler()
            }))
            parent.presentAlert(alert: alert)
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                completionHandler(true)
            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
                completionHandler(false)
            }))
            parent.presentAlert(alert: alert)
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: prompt, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addTextField { textField in
                textField.text = defaultText
            }
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                completionHandler(alert.textFields?.first?.text)
            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
                completionHandler(nil)
            }))
            parent.presentAlert(alert: alert)
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, requestMediaCapturePermissionFor origin: WKSecurityOrigin, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, type: WKMediaCaptureType, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKPermissionDecision) -> Void) {
            decisionHandler(.grant)
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
            print("Navigation error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true 
        webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []

        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = context.coordinator
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        requestMicrophoneAccess()
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }

    func requestMicrophoneAccess() {
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission { granted in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if granted {
                    print("Microphone access granted")
                } else {
                    print("Microphone access denied")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func presentAlert(alert: UIAlertController) {
        if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
           let rootViewController = windowScene.windows.first?.rootViewController {
            rootViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

I have implemented the above code and given all permission in entitlements file.
